# React - passing font awesome icon as a prop

Tags: reactjs, icons, font-awesome, element, react-props

I am using a font awesome asterisk to indicate a required form input, passing it as a prop to a form input component. Rather than being rendered it is rendering [object Object] instead.

The props:

```
<FormInput
      label={"Title " + (<i className="fas fa-asterisk fa-1x"></i>)}
      id="title"
      value={title}
      onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'title')}
/>
```

The component:

```
const FormInput = ({ value, label, onChange, id }) => {
    return (
        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor={id}>{label}</InputLabel>
            <Input
                id={id}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </FormControl>
    );
};
```

How can I render an html element passed as a prop? Any help appreciated.